# Combine similar XML records/fields with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, transform

I am trying to combine similar records (same UniqueID) with XSL.

Here is my XML:

```
<ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">1234</field>
    <field name="Location">Michigan</field>
    <field name="Category">Math</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">1234</field>
    <field name="Location">Texas</field>
    <field name="Category">Science</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">1234</field>
    <field name="Location"></field>
    <field name="Category">History</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">2345</field>
    <field name="Location">Ohio</field>
    <field name="Category"></field>
  </record>
</ExportXML>
```

Here's what I'd like the output to look like:

```
<ExportXML>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">1234</field>
    <field name="Location">Michigan, Texas</field>
    <field name="Category">Math, Science, History</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">2345</field>
    <field name="Location">Ohio</field>
    <field name="Category"></field>
  </record>
</ExportXML>
```

I've tried so many different things that my head is spinning.  I'm still new to this, and I'm finding it difficult to learn.

I'm probably way off, but here's what I have so far.  To start I was just trying to merge one of the fields (Category) but it just repeats all the records without attempting to merge...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:t="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
exclude-result-prefixes="t">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="distinctRecord" match="t:record" use="t:field[@name='UniqueID']" />

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="//t:record[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('distinctRecord', t:field[@name='UniqueID'])[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="UniqueID" select="t:field[@name='UniqueID']" />
    <record>
          <UniqueID><xsl:value-of select="$UniqueID" /></UniqueID>
          <Category>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('distinctRecord', $UniqueID)">
                  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:value-of select="t:field[@name='Category']"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Category>
    </record>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Your input XML isn't well-formed; would you mind fixing that? Also, your XSLT stylesheet uses a namespace that isn't present in your input XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your posted input sample is not well-formed, when correcting it I get

```
<ExportXML>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">1234</field>
    <field name="Location">Michigan</field>
    <field name="Category">Math</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">1234</field>
    <field name="Location">Texas</field>
    <field name="Category">Science</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">1234</field>
    <field name="Location"></field>
    <field name="Category">History</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="UniqueID">2345</field>
    <field name="Location">Ohio</field>
    <field name="Category"></field>
  </record>
</ExportXML>
```

then your posted XSLT does use a namespace although the input does not have any, correcting the XSLT I get

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="distinctRecord" match="record" use="field[@name='UniqueID']" />

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="//record[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('distinctRecord', field[@name='UniqueID'])[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="UniqueID" select="field[@name='UniqueID']" />
    <record>
          <UniqueID><xsl:value-of select="$UniqueID" /></UniqueID>
          <Category>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('distinctRecord', $UniqueID)">
                  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='Category']"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Category>
    </record>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then I think you get the grouping you want:

```
<record>
   <UniqueID>1234</UniqueID>
   <Category>Math, Science, History</Category>
</record>
<record>
   <UniqueID>2345</UniqueID>
   <Category/>
</record>
```

You can then further edit the XSLT to create a root element and to add the location e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="distinctRecord" match="record" use="field[@name='UniqueID']" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <ExportXML>
  <xsl:for-each select="//record[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('distinctRecord', field[@name='UniqueID'])[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="UniqueID" select="field[@name='UniqueID']" />
    <record>
          <UniqueID><xsl:value-of select="$UniqueID" /></UniqueID>
          <Location><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='Location']"/></Location>
          <Category>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('distinctRecord', $UniqueID)">
                  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='Category']"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Category>
    </record>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </ExportXML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the main grouping in your XSLT is correctly coded, only you need to make sure you apply it to a well-formed XML input.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is dependent upon you having access to XSLT 2.0  (Saxon 9.0 or higher)  I am using Saxon 9.4.0.4.
This allows the use of "for each group".

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:t="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
exclude-result-prefixes="t">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="t:ExportXML">
    <ExportXML>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="t:record" group-by="t:field[@name='UniqueID']">
            <record>
                <field name="UniqueID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="t:field[@name='UniqueID']"></xsl:value-of>
                </field>
                <field name="Location">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:if test="position() != 1  and  t:field[@name='Location'] &gt; ' '">,</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="t:field[@name='Location']"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </field>
                <field name="Category">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:if test="position() != 1  and  t:field[@name='Category'] &gt; ' '">,</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="t:field[@name='Category']"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </field>
            </record>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ExportXML>
</xsl:template>
```