# XML Record Merging with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I am trying to combine multiple records using XSLT from a Microsoft Access Export, however I cannot find out how to combine these records based on a unique ID.

The sample source would be:

```
<dataroot>
<Record>
    <OrderID>123</OrderID>
    <ItemID>1</ItemID>
</Record>
<Record>
    <OrderID>123</OrderID>
    <ItemID>2</ItemID>
</Record>
```

And what I would like it to look like would be:

```
<Record>
<OrderID>123</OrderID>
<ItemSet>
    <ItemID>1</ItemID>
    <ItemID>2</ItemID>
</ItemSet>
```

I've found this other question asked regarding a similar problem, however this goes on attributes and I am unable to find a way to go based on the value.

[Combine similar XML records/fields with XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980892/combine-similar-xml-records-fields-with-xsl)

I would use the for-each-group but Access does not support it in its transforms.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a FAQ - see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I didn't search by the term "grouping" but this will definitely help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following using Access 2010 and it worked for me. With this table named [Record]

```
OrderID  ItemID
-------  ------
    123       1
    123       2
    234       3
    234       4
    234       5
```

and this XSLT file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:key name="record" match="Record" use="OrderID" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </dataroot>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:for-each select="Record[count(. | key('record', OrderID)[1]) = 1]">
      <Record>
        <xsl:copy-of select="OrderID" />
        <ItemSet>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('record',OrderID)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="ItemID" />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ItemSet>
      </Record>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when I export the table to XML using the above transform

[image: ExportXML.png]

I get this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
  <Record>
    <OrderID>123</OrderID>
    <ItemSet>
      <ItemID>1</ItemID>
      <ItemID>2</ItemID>
    </ItemSet>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <OrderID>234</OrderID>
    <ItemSet>
      <ItemID>3</ItemID>
      <ItemID>4</ItemID>
      <ItemID>5</ItemID>
    </ItemSet>
  </Record>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: `<xsl:for-each-group>` is an XSLT 2.0 instruction. AFAIK, Microsoft does not support XSLT 2.0 in any of their products - and your stylesheet doesn't use it either.

Comment: Looks perfect for what I need to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on what Micheal has suggested, I think you are looking into something like this,

```
  <xsl:key name="record" match="Record" use="OrderID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="Record[count(. | key('record', OrderID)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="OrderID"/>
        <ItemSet>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('record',OrderID)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="ItemID"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ItemSet>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```